# Is it possible to predict the next output for the str_shuffle function in PHP?

Tags: php, security, random, reverse-engineering, random-seed

I'm doing a bit of a research on the `str_shuffle()` function and i was wondering can i predict the next output of the function if i know the seed?

Internals of `str_shuffle()`

```
 while (--n_left) {
     rnd_idx = php_rand();
     RAND_RANGE(rnd_idx, 0, n_left, PHP_RAND_MAX); // <-- on some versions of php i couldn't find this here
     if (rnd_idx != n_left) {
         temp = str[n_left];
         str[n_left] = str[rnd_idx];
         str[rnd_idx] = temp;
     }
 }
```

Where RAND_RANGE is:

```
#define RAND_RANGE(__n, __min, __max, __tmax) (__n) = php_mt_rand_range((__min), (__max))
```

With this information i concluded that it uses the **Fisher-Yates** algorithm, so i wrote a little test script:

```
mt_srand(101); // seed it with a random value
echo str_shuffle("testcase"); // gives "acetsets"
```

By working backwards i concluded that the values of the `rnd_idx` were **2, 3, 2, 3, 0, 1, 0**.

But when i try to print them to make sure using:

```
mt_srand(101);
$a = "testcase";
$c = strlen($a);
for($i = $c - 1;$i > 0;--$i)
    echo mt_rand(0,$i) . '<br>';
```

It gives me **0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 1, 1** which is not the same. What am i missing? I know it's possible to "break" the `str_shuffle()` because it uses the **Mersenne Twister** which doesn't produce cryptographically safe random numbers, but how?